# How much of a "large" object gets brought in to the cache?

Tags: c++, performance, caching, cpu, cpu-architecture

If I have an object which contains several large vectors, if I access one of the vector data members does it mean the other vectors (I havent accessed) also get brought in to the cache (possibly by the rule of spatial locality of code)?

So if I had:

```
class A{
    float p;
    int x[10000];
    int y[10000];
};
```

and I was only accessing `p` in a particular piece of code, would accessing `A::p` pollute the cache more so than

```
class B{
    float p;
    int x[10000];
    double y;
};
```

because `B` is smaller due to only having one large array.

My instinct is that only frequently-accesed cache lines are loaded- not the whole object.

Comment: Caching behavior is machine dependent. If you load one piece of memory the surrounding memory is likely going to be cached as well, but the size of the memory being cached has nothing to do with how your struct looks like, because your machine doesn't know what a struct is and doesn't care that you think its members belong together.

Comment: A cache line is a certain size -- maybe 128 bytes.  If any byte within that line must be accessed then the entire line is brought in (even bytes in unrelated objects).  In the simplest cache scheme, no additional bytes are brought in until they are referenced.

Comment: Just a comment: You are talking about vectors but your example uses c arrays. This doesn't have an influence on the answer, but as far as memory layout is concerned, these are two completely different things. Vectors manage their memory on a separate memory region on the heap, whereas the variables of a c-array are actually allocated within the objects memory region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in other answers, the memory subsystem doesn't know about the memory layout of your objects. It only sees memory access to the respective address. As a result, the same amount of data will always be loaded into the cache, irrespective of how big your objects are.

As for the question of how much data is loaded, this depends on the architecture.  On simple system only the respective cacheline will be loaded. Modern x86 cpu on the other hand also have a prefetching mechanism. This mechanism tries to determine which memory addresses you will most likely need next and will also fetch those cache lines in advance. This is the reason why sequential access is much faster (orders of magnitude) than random access, because here the prefetcher will always pick the right data.

Edit:
But again: This has nothing to do with the size of your class, but only depends on the access pattern (which might of course be depending on the memory layout of your class).

Answer (score 2):

The machine knows **nothing** about the layout of your class, so the class size is irrelevant.   It only knows what memory you *actually access*, i.e. your access pattern. The layout information of the class probably even won't *exist* in memory once the code is compiled, so the machine won't be figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

A cache line corresponding to the address you read from is loaded, irrespective of the object.

This depends on your platform. For a cache line of 64 bytes (so 8 or 16 integers), depending on alignment, reading any of `x[0...15]` will result in only those elements loaded in the cache.

Reading element `x[16]` will load it and subsequent elements in a different cache line.

Depending on the total size of the cache, reading, say `x[9000]`, could result in a cache collision and a previously filled line will be cleared to make room for the new elements.